# How to get Log4j2 RollingFileAppender to create new log file and roll existing files

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

How do I configure log4j2 (currently using V2.13.3) to create a new log file each time the app starts, and to roll any existing files, up to a maximum of 10 files?

E.g. the 1st time the app runs it creates `test.log`. The 2nd time it runs the existing `test.log` gets renamed and the app starts logging to a fresh `test.log`. And so on.

I tried the following config:

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile
                name="file"
                fileName="test.log"
                filePattern="test-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}-%i.log"
                append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%c{2}] [%t]%n[%p] : %m%n"/>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="1"/>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

However the rolled log file never gets created - log4j2 just keeps overwriting `test.log` each time. My guess is that log4j2 is creating the new log file before the OnStartupTriggeringPolicy is invoked, consequently the policy determines that a rolled log file is not required. AFAICS this seems like a bug.

If I change the `append="false"` flag to `append="true"`, then the rolling files get created, however the 1st time I run the app it creates both `test.log` and `test-yyyymmdd-hhmmss-1.log` file (the latter is empty), and for each subsequent run it keeps creating a rolled file with the original `test-yyyymmdd-hhmmss-n.log` filename, e.g.:

```
test-20200715-120227-1.log
test-20200715-120227-2.log
test-20200715-120227-3.log
```

(I would expect each rolled file to have a different hhmmss time).

Weirdly, if (keeping `append="true"`) I add a `.gz` suffix to the rolled log filename,:

```
filePattern="test-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}-%i.log.gz"
```

than I get the desired behaviour:

```
test-20200715-143142-1.log.gz
test-20200715-143149-1.log.gz
test-20200715-143153-1.log.gz
```

Comment: is the latter populated when the app starts or restarts? it might be empty as a place holder

Comment: If you mean the test-yyyymmdd-hhmmss-1.log file, it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

OnStartupTriggerPolicy should go under Policies tag

`<Policies> <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="1"/> </Policies>`

I would try something like this:

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile
                name="file"
                fileName="test.log"
                filePattern="test-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}-%i.log"
                append="false"
                bufferedIO="false"
        >
            <PatternLayout> 
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%c{2}] [%t]%n[%p] : %m%n
                </Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="1"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: If there is only one policy the Policies element is not required.

Answer (score -1):

You have a time pattern in your file name pattern but you do not have a time-based rollover policy. You also have %i without a size-based rollover policy. It may be a bug that without any other policy the onstartup policy doesn't know what to do because it expects some other policy to be present. I would have to check that.

Also, specifying max=10 on the DefaultRolloverStrategy is unlikely to accomplish anything. That setting means "keep only 10 files within the 'window' of the rollover policy". If you had a time-based rollover of 24 hours and a size-based rollover that caused 20 rollovers a day only 10 of those would be kept. But on day 2 you would have 20, on day 3 you would have 30, etc.

I would suggest something like this:

```
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile
            name="file"
            fileName="test.log"
            filePattern="test-%i.log"
            append="false"
            bufferedIO="false"
    >
        <PatternLayout> 
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%c{2}] [%t]%n[%p] : %m%n
            </Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="1"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size=50MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. If I'm doing this wrong then what's the correct way to achieve the stated aim?

Comment: Other than at startup, when do you want files to roll over?

Comment: Ideally once they reach a preconfigured max size, e.g. 50MB.

Comment: Just tried that config and it doesn't roll the log file at all. It just overwrites test.log each time.